# Receiving strange characters from GPS tracker, is this HEX or binary?

Tags: gps, server, string, tracking, binary

I am struggling with a GSM GPS tracker. It looks like a clone of GT02A, and it is a relatively common model.

My problem is that when it sends data to my server, it is not readable. I set it to send on port `333` and then on server I am listening on port `333` and the string received (looking in Putty terminal) looks like this:

```
Rg!r▒▒▒
xx
;▒
▒1▒▒[▒F▒f▒W
▒1▒▒▒[▒F▒f▒W
▒13▒▒[▒F▒f▒W
▒
xx
}▒
▒1▒▒[▒F▒f▒W
xx
▒1 :m▒F▒f▒W
▒1!▒u▒F▒f▒W
xx
"▒/
▒1#▒▒▒F▒f▒W
▒1$▒▒[▒F▒f▒W
▒1%o▒[▒F▒f▒W
```

Can anyone tell what the problem is or if this string is a HEX or binary string of some kind that needs to be decoded ? 
The device seems to work fine if I request the location by SMS, it sends it correctly, so it is not fried or anything.